# SumIf certain values are in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, sumifs

I want to sum up all values that go for a certain country.

I tried:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B7;D2=$A$2:$A$7)
```

However, I get `0` back as seen in the picture below.

[image]

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the 'test' range and the 'sum' range as separate parameters: try

```
=SUMIF($A2:$A7; D2; $B2:$B7)
```

Comment: The OP should just need to change the commas to semi-colons (per the regional settings used in the example).